# laser_filters LaserScanRangeFilter not publishing

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, laser-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the LaserScanRangeFilter to remove points that are far away. However, nothing is published on the topics it should be mapping to.

Here is my `laser_filter_config.yaml`:

```
scan_filter_chain:
  - name: range
    type: laser_filters/LaserScanRangeFilter
    params:
      use_message_range_limits: false
      lower_threshold: 0.0
      upper_threshold: 2.0
      lower_replacement_value: -.inf
      upper_replacement_value: .inf
```

Here is my launch file (I am using the Autonomous Research Kit provided by Clearpath for the Husky robot):

```
<launch>
  <!-- We want to wait for the ARK to start up, so we don't run right away -->
  <arg name="node_start_delay" default="4.0" />  
  <arg name="route" default="$(dirname)/../config/route.json"/>

  <!-- Start the ARK navigation server -->
  <include file="$(find husky_cpr_ark_navigation)/launch/husky_ark_navigation.launch">
      <arg name="front_laser" value="/front/scan_processed"/>
      <arg name="rear_laser" value="/rear/scan_processed"/>
  </include>

  <node pkg="laser_filters" type="scan_to_scan_filter_chain" output="screen"
      name="laser_filter">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(dirname)/../config/laser_filter_config.yaml" />
    <remap from="/front/scan" to="/front/scan_processed" />
    <remap from="/rear/scan" to="/rear/scan_processed" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

I can do `rostopic echo /front/scan` and `rostopic echo /rear/scan` and I see the lidars are generating data, but nothing appears when I do `rostopoic echo /front/scan_processed` or  `rostopoic echo /rear/scan_processed`.

I also looked at `rqt_graph` and there is nothing going in or out of the `laser_filter` node.

I would really appreciate any advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375732/laser_filters-laserscanrangefilter-not-publishing/) by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to figure this out. The issue was I didn't realize how `remap` worked. [This](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) helped a lot.

Here is a working launch file:

```
<launch>
  <!-- We want to wait for the ARK to start up, so we don't run right away -->
  <arg name="node_start_delay" default="4.0" />  
  <arg name="route" default="$(dirname)/../config/route.json"/>

  <!-- Start the ARK navigation server -->
  <include file="$(find husky_cpr_ark_navigation)/launch/husky_ark_navigation.launch">
      <arg name="front_laser" value="/front/scan_processed"/>
      <arg name="rear_laser" value="/rear/scan_processed"/>
  </include>

  <node pkg="laser_filters" type="scan_to_scan_filter_chain" output="screen"
      name="laser_filter_front">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(dirname)/../config/laser_filter_config.yaml" />
    <remap from="scan" to="/front/scan" />
    <remap from="scan_filtered" to="/front/scan_processed" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="laser_filters" type="scan_to_scan_filter_chain" output="screen"
      name="laser_filter_rear">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(dirname)/../config/laser_filter_config.yaml" />
    <remap from="scan" to="/rear/scan" />
    <remap from="scan_filtered" to="/rear/scan_processed" />
  </node>

  <!-- Launch the custom husky_ark node -->
  <node pkg="husky_ark_armlab" type="husky_ark_armlab.py" 
    name="husky_ark_armlab" output="screen" launch-prefix="bash -c 'sleep $(arg node_start_delay); $0 $@' "
    args="--route $(arg route)">
      <rosparam command="load" file="$(dirname)/../config/default.yaml" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) with karma: 15 on 2021-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-01-22**:
@EricW I have been having issues trying to figure a way to use laser_filter, I don't believe my launch file is correct. Could you please spare the time to look at at my question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/394794/laser_filter-not-working/)